# Converts numbers to english equivalent string form

Tags: vb.net

can you help me make this program that converts the input number to an English equivalent string formed from the digits. for example, 123 represented by "one two three" and 4017 by "four zero one seven" using select case?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Read www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask proper questions.

Comment: Use `Dictionary` will be you best solution.

Comment: @ Cristene Parajas, we hope that your issue has been resolved. May I suggest some further reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work... regards...

Answer (score 0):

The `Choose` function comes in handy in such situations. Loop thru each digit in the number and store its equivalent word in a `StringBuilder`.

```
Function NumberToWords(ByVal number As Long) As String
    Dim words As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For Each digit In number.ToString
        If digit = "0"c Then
            words.Append("zero")
        Else
            words.Append(Choose(CInt(digit.ToString), "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"))
        End If
        words.Append(" ")
    Next
    Return words.ToString.Trim
End Function
```

Just in case if you are looking for a true number to words converter, the following article may be of help to you:
https://pradeep1210.wordpress.com/2014/09/09/number-to-words-converter/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

Private Words As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)

Sub Main()
    Words.Add("Zero", "0")
    Words.Add("One", "1")
    Words.Add("Two", "2")
    Words.Add("Three", "3")
    Words.Add("Four", "4")
    Words.Add("Five", "5")
    Words.Add("Six", "6")
    Words.Add("Seven", "7")
    Words.Add("Eight", "8")
    Words.Add("Nine", "9")

    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to conver to words")
    Dim s As String = Console.ReadLine().ToString

    Console.WriteLine(ConvertNumbersToWords(s))

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub

Private Function ConvertNumbersToWords(number As String)
    Dim ret As New StringBuilder

    For i As Integer = 0 To number.Length - 1
        ret.Append((From w In Words Where w.Value.Equals(number.ElementAt(i)) Select w.Key).First).Append(" ")
    Next

    Return ret.ToString.Trim
End Function

End Module
```